# SQL Server- An older report .rdl opens only XML even in Report Builder. How to convert the XML to SQL?

Tags: sql-server, xml

An older report I am trying to edit, when opened in the MSVS Report Builder, only opens XML. Can't read any SQL.

**The code reads as follows:**

```
<Hierarchies>
<Hierarchy>
  <BaseEntity>
    <!--Plate-->
    <EntityID>G121a636b-1459-40b5-9b58-7e427e6b5ce8</EntityID>
  </BaseEntity>
  <Groupings>
    <Grouping Name="Account">
      <Expression Name="Account">
        <Path>
          <RolePathItem>
            <!--Account-->
            <RoleID>G26e62fb8-dd29-4f29-ae1d-232cd94977e3</RoleID>
          </RolePathItem>
        </Path>
        <EntityRef>
          <!--Account-->
          <EntityID>Gf797726f-8cff-417a-992e-c532e2906775</EntityID>
        </EntityRef>
      </Expression>
      <Details>
......
.....
...
```

Any idea how I can read or convert this to SQL?

Comment: This doesn't look like code and it doesn't look anything like a report.  Is this your data?

Comment: When I import the .rdl file into Report Builder so I can edit it, this is what I get when I open up the Dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I just opened the file in Notepad, edited out the values I needed to and pasted the code back in the file and ran the report. Worked fine.

Unfortunately, this was just a work-around and not a real solution to it.